# Kryo serialization error only on Tabs

Tags: java, android, serialization, kryo

I got this issue: my multiplayer game developed with the kryonet libraries works like a charm on every device but rarely it crashes on a galaxy tab. The error it shows is:

> E/AndroidRuntime(16861): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-30
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16861): com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException:
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: start=0 end=5
>   data.length=512 index=6 length=5 E/AndroidRuntime(16861):
>   Serialization trace: E/AndroidRuntime(16861): email
>   (com.momasoft.sudokutournament.network.Network$Login)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16861): at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:203)

I really don't know what the problem is. My Login class is properly registered and contains only 2 strings. This works on almost every device but the galaxy tab. How can I fix it?